# Automatically fetch data every 10 minute (Simple html dom)

Tags: simple-html-dom

im working on a project, where i want to fetch last minute flights and then save them into my database. The problem is that i don't want scrape everytime the user visits the website and then save into my database because that will only cause alot of duplicates. Can i somehow make the website fetch the data for me on a scheduled time and then delete previous records in the database?

Comment: The scrape+save shouldn't be triggered by a browser at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the OS to execute a task periodically, cron job is what you want.

Either get the cron job to call your program via the command line, or use wget to fetch the page that would trigger the data fetching.

More on cron jobs:
http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml